# jqgrid Allow only one cell per row to be selected. Not working after a sort is performed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

My goal is to be able to highlight a cell when clicked and remove highlight when clicked again. Each row can have only one cell highlighted. I have attempted to get it to work but whenever the grid is sorted, my target functionality doesn't seem to work anymore. Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.
Here is the demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hoalzein/hwondp71/9/)
I believe the problem lies around here...

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var gridParams = jQuery(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");
    var selectedCells = gridParams.mySelection;
    var rowId, columnName, cellValue;
    if (selectedCells.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedCells.length; i++) {
            rowId = selectedCells[i].rowId;
            columnName = selectedCells[i].columnName;
            cellValue = selectedCells[i].cellValue;
            jQuery(this).setCell(rowId, columnName, cellValue, 'ui-state-highlight', '', true);
            jQuery(this).jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowId).columnName = cellValue;
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question (and your [issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/462)) isn't easy. Thus I'm answering with delay.

First of all, you **have to** include some unique `id` values in your data to be sure that rowids will stay *unchanged* after sorting the data. As the values you can use any unique values, for example, 1, 2, ..., 5 or 10, 20, ... 50 or any other values. I changed the input data from your demo to the following:

```
var data = [
        { id: 10, win: 50, draw: 20, defeat: 30 },
        { id: 20, win: 40, draw: 10, defeat: 50 },
        { id: 30, win: 30, draw: 50, defeat: 20 },
        { id: 40, win: 20, draw: 60, defeat: 20 },
        { id: 50, win: 70, draw: 20, defeat: 10 }
    ];
```

The next problem: the information, which you saves in `mySelection` parameter. Your current implementation saves array of objects with the following properties: `rowId`, `cellId`, `columnName`, `cellValue` and `selectedCell`, where `selectedCell` is DOM element which represent selected `<td>` element. I find not good saving `selectedCell` because the content of grid will be **rebuild** after sorting and the `selectedCell` will point to DOM element *removed* from HTML page. Additionally, you searing elements in `mySelection` by rowid (see the code of `returnExistingRowSelectedCells` function). The code could be reduced to one line if you would modify the information saved in `mySelection` to the map: column name by rowid. For example, if you select 3 cells in the grid like on the picture below

[image]

then the current implementation will hold `mySelection` like

```
[{
    "rowId": "20",
    "selectedCell": {...},
    "cellId": "20_draw",
    "columnName": "draw",
    "cellValue": 10
}, {
    "rowId": "40",
    "selectedCell": {...},
    "cellId": "40_win",
    "columnName": "win",
    "cellValue": 20
}, {
    "rowId": "30",
    "selectedCell": {...},
    "cellId": "30_defeat",
    "columnName": "defeat",
    "cellValue": 20
}]
```

(in your original demo `rowId` was the values like `"jqg4"`, `"jqg2"` and `"jqg3"`). I suggest to replace the array to the object like

```
{
    "20": "draw",
    "40": "win",
    "30": "defeat"
}
```

I uses column names instead of column indexes to be sure that one don't need to update the data if the order of columns will be changed by drag & drop column headers (one need to add to the demo `jquery-ui.min.js` of cause to make the option `sortable: true`, which you use workable).

The last remark is about addressing of cells by column name. Free jqGrid hold internal parameter `iColByName`, which allows to get column index by column name (`gridParams.iColByName[colName]`). Additionally the method `getGridRowById` can be used to get `<tr>` by rowid and then one van use `$.jgrid.getCell` to get jQuery wrapper to the cell (`<td>`) by column index:

```
var tr = $(this).jqGrid("getGridRowById", rowid);
var $td = $jgrid.getCell.call(this, tr, iCol); // mostly $(tr.cells[iCol]);
```

In the way you need just hold rowid and the column name and the get `$td` having the information. You can then use `$td.addClass("ui-state-highlight")` or `$td.removeClass("ui-state-highlight")` for selection/deselection the cell.

The modified code could be like the following

```
mySelection: {},
loadComplete: function() {
  var $this = jQuery(this), gridParams = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam"),
      selectedCells = gridParams.mySelection,  rowId, tr, iCol, $td;

  for (rowId in selectedCells) {
      if (selectedCells.hasOwnProperty(rowId)) {
          tr = $this.jqGrid("getGridRowById", rowId);
          iCol = gridParams.iColByName[selectedCells[rowId]];
          $td = jQuery.jgrid.getCell.call(this, tr, iCol);
          $td.addClass("ui-state-highlight");
      }
  }
},
onCellSelect: function(rowId, iCol, cellContent, element) {
  var $this = jQuery(this),
      gridParams = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam"),
      selectedCells = gridParams.mySelection;
  if (selectedCells[rowId]) {
      // some sell is already selected in the row
      var tr = $this.jqGrid("getGridRowById", rowId),
          iColSelected = gridParams.iColByName[selectedCells[rowId]],
          $tdSelected = jQuery.jgrid.getCell.call(this, tr, iColSelected);
      $tdSelected.removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
      if (gridParams.iColByName[selectedCells[rowId]] === iCol) {
          // the current cell will be unselected
          delete selectedCells[rowId];
          return;
      }
  }
  // select the cell
  jQuery(element.target).closest("td").addClass("ui-state-highlight");
  // update column name in mySelection
  selectedCells[rowId] = gridParams.colModel[iCol].name;
},
beforeSelectRow: function(rowId, element) {
  return false;
},
```

See the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/hwondp71/37/.

Comment: Thanks a million Oleg. I see where my logical error was, the point that saving "selectedCell" as DOM element made a huge impact to the required functionality. I 100% agree with you and your opinion. Your solution couldn't be more PERFECT !!! I really appreciate your time and effort, God Bless !!!